# Service does not have load balancer ingress IP - Devops

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, azure-aks

I have a deployment configuration in my helm chart,

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: {{ template "userapi.fullname" . }}
  labels:
    app: {{ template "userapi.name" . }}
    chart: {{ template "userapi.chart" . }}
    release: {{ .Release.Name }}
    heritage: {{ .Release.Service }}
spec:
  replicas: {{ .Values.replicaCount }}
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: {{ template "userapi.name" . }}
      release: {{ .Release.Name }}
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: {{ template "userapi.name" . }}
        release: {{ .Release.Name }}
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: {{ .Chart.Name }}
          image: "{{ .Values.image.repository }}:{{ .Values.image.tag }}"
          imagePullPolicy: {{ .Values.image.pullPolicy }}
          ports:
            - name: http
              containerPort: {{ .Values.service.port }}
              protocol: TCP
          livenessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /
              port: http
            initialDelaySeconds: 30
          readinessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /
              port: http
            initialDelaySeconds: 30
```

Also, I have configured my cluster, basically this is my configuration:

```
az group create --name demorg --location eastus

    az aks create \
    --resource-group demorg \
    --name democluster \
    --node-count 1 \
    --vm-set-type VirtualMachineScaleSets \
    --load-balancer-sku standard \
    --enable-cluster-autoscaler \
    --min-count 1 \
    --max-count 3
    
    az acr create --resource-group demorg --name acrdemo --sku Standard
```

But I'm getting this error:

> history.go:53: [debug] getting history for release userapi
> 2021-04-19T07:24:14.7353557Z Release "userapi" does not exist.
> Installing it now. 2021-04-19T07:24:14.7354630Z install.go:172:
> [debug] Original chart version: "" 2021-04-19T07:24:14.7357809Z
> install.go:189: [debug] CHART PATH:
> /home/vsts/work/r1/a/_userapi-CI/dropuser/userapi-v0.4.0.tgz
> 2021-04-19T07:24:14.7360391Z  2021-04-19T07:24:14.7397152Z
> client.go:109: [debug] creating 2 resource(s)
> 2021-04-19T07:24:14.7397607Z wait.go:53: [debug] beginning wait for 2
> resources with timeout of 2m0s 2021-04-19T07:24:14.7398121Z
> wait.go:206: [debug] Service does not have load balancer ingress IP
> address: demospace/userapi 2021-04-19T07:24:14.7398987Z wait.go:225:
> [debug] Deployment is not ready: demospace/userapi. 0 out of 2
> expected pods are ready 2021-04-19T07:24:14.7441027Z Error: timed out
> waiting for the condition 2021-04-19T07:24:14.7441419Z helm.go:81:
> [debug] timed out waiting for the condition
> 2021-04-19T07:24:14.7468168Z ##[error]history.go:53: [debug] getting
> history for release userapi

How I can solve it? I tried with several ways and I'm not finding a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> [debug] Deployment is not ready: demospace/userapi. 0 out of 2 expected pods are ready

Check what is wrong with your app, e.g. check the application logs.

E.g. first list your pods with:

```
kubectl get pods
```

Then you get the names of your pods. Now you want to see the application logs, and hopefully you are logging why the application is not Ready (e.g. responding on the ReadinessProbe on path `/`). Check logs with:

```
kubectl logs <pod-name>
```